# Submit Form and send email to mail id without database

Tags: html, contact-form

I am making a website and there is a contact form.On submitting the contact form it should send the message from the contact form to the the desired mail id.Locally I can use the xampp database but I don't have a database when I am going to host it live.So is there any other way we can end email using a contact form without using a database.I am new to this and Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can send email without the database.You can just fetch the email ID to which you need to send email in the contact form. You can send the email ID to AJAX function and use php `mail()` to send the email to the contact.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about with ajax.Could you give me any other way or explain how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    mail($_POST['emailaddress'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'];
    // you can pass 4th parameter as headers 
}
```

Comment: Yup. See in code, we just call pre-defined function mail() and no linking with database. So it will call without db.